# Using a Result Set From a Sub SELECT When Duplicate Rows are Encountered

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, duplicates, having

First of all, the table I'm struggling with:

```
DispatchLocations
=================
DispatchID        int
StopNumber        int
Arrived           bool
Departed          bool
```

The idea is that on a trucking route, there are many stops in a dispatch. This is a list of each location on each dispatch (essentially, it's a route table). In this view, there should only be one dispatch for each row of output, which points to the "current stop" that the dispatch is at.

```
SELECT TOP 4
  DispatchID,
  Min(StopNumber) AS NextStop,
  Arrived,
  Departed
FROM DispatchLocations
GROUP BY 
  DispatchID,
  Arrived, Departed
HAVING (Arrived = 0 OR Departed = 0)
ORDER BY DispatchID ASC, NextStop ASC
```

My view's output as of now:

```
Dispatch_ID    NextStop    Arrived    Departed
===========    ========    =======    ========
3              2           False      False
1356           2           False      False
6410           1           True       False
6410           2           False      False
```

The last row is being dumped in because the GROUP BY must include the arrival and departure status, breaking the uniqueness of the output.

The desired rows (only) can be extracted using a very similar query:

```
SELECT
  DispatchID,
  Min(StopNumber) AS NextStop,
  Arrived,
  Departed
FROM DispatchLocations
GROUP BY 
  DispatchID,
  Arrived, Departed
HAVING
  (Arrived = 1 AND Departed = 0) AND Min(StopNumber) = 1
ORDER BY DispatchID ASC

Dispatch_ID    NextStop    Arrived    Departed
===========    ========    =======    ========
6410           1           True       False
50589          1           True       False
50687          1           True       False
```

I verified these results by selecting all DispatchIDs from my view `WHERE COUNT(DispatchID) > 1`.

How can I use the results from the second query whenever I encounter those matching IDs in the view? I can't get an `EXIST` or an `EXCEPT` clause to work with `HAVING` present in the query text. So for now I'm taking the results set off the database's hands, and having the application logic sort through any duplicate results, and keeping only the first one encountered for each dispatch ID. But I'd rather have the database do this for me.

## UPDATE

I'm using SSMS 2008, which builds views with a `TOP 100 PERCENT` included by default. Here's the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/n8Q8i27T) of the original.

Comment: What RDBMS is this?  I'm guessing not SQL Server since  you have `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW`.

Comment: @JNK - `ORDER BY` can be used with `TOP` in a view or where any valid table expression is expected

Comment: @JCooper I realize that, but notice there is no `TOP` in the posted view definition

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT  dl.DispatchID,
        dl.StopNumber AS NextStop,
        dl.Arrived,
        dl.Departed
FROM    DispatchLocations dl
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  DispatchID, MIN(StopNumber) [StopNumber]
            FROM    DispatchLocations
            GROUP BY DispatchID
        ) MinDL
            ON MinDL.DispatchID = dl.DispatchID
            AND MinDL.StopNumber = dl.StopNumber
```

This will return the details for the lowest stopnumber for each dispatch ID. You can then filter this further by simply using `WHERE`. E.g.

```
WHERE  Arrived = 1
AND    Departed = 0
```

I think adding the above to the select statement at the top will bring back the results:

```
Dispatch_ID    NextStop    Arrived    Departed
===========    ========    =======    ========
6410           1           True       False
50589          1           True       False
50687          1           True       False
```

Although I may have completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think I tried something along these lines already, but I'll give my derived table a rebuild at work in the morning. Ill post an update then.