# SQL Composite key grouping issue

Tags: sql, group-by, composite-key, unique-constraint

I've got a very frustrating SQL issue which i can't for the life of me solve with a derived query returning a composite key but also performing a MIN() aggregate function on another field within that table. If i was performing the MIN() on one of the composite keys it would be easy, but since i need to return both keys and perform the MIN() function as well to the outer query i can't work out how to do this. The entire query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    p.name as productname
   ,tmp.packageid
   ,tmp.price
   ,ppk2.packageoptionid
   ,ppk2.selcomproductid
FROM ( 
        SELECT ppk.productid, ppk.packageid, MIN(ppk.price) as price
        FROM  product_package ppk
                 INNER JOIN package pk ON ppk.packageid = pk.id
                 INNER JOIN [plan] pl ON pk.planid = pl.id
        WHERE pk.networkid = 1
        GROUP BY ppk.productid, ppk.packageid
) tmp
INNER JOIN product_package ppk2 ON ( 
        ppk2.productid = tmp.productid 
    AND ppk2.packageid = tmp.packageid
)    
INNER JOIN product p ON (p.id = ppk2.productid)  
WHERE p.isenabled = 1;
```

Current Results:

```
--------------------------------------
productid   |   packageid   |   price
1               500             0
1               501             19.95
1               502             29.95
2               501             0
3               500             15    
3               504             39.95
```

Desired Results:

```
--------------------------------------
productid   |   packageid   |   price
1               500             0
2               501             0
3               500             15
```

The derived query "tmp" is where my issue lies as i need a unique rows back for each product/package combination with the lowest price, before joining onto the outer tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good question. Now: can you please sign up for a [pastebin account](http://pastebin.com/) so that we don't have to look at those ugly slider bars that stackoverflow puts around around your code? `:)`

Comment: @Droogans or you could just format the code...

Comment: @ninesided: Touche, good sir.

Comment: @Droogans: I don't know about you, but I skip any question involving a pastebin account.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Ninesided, I shouldn't have considered lower resolutions sorry.

Comment: I wouldn't use it at all if there was a way I could specify in the formatted text of my quesiton some kind of `[collapse] [/collapse]` tag pair. I skip any question involving an enormous raw code dump.

Comment: Sorry i meant i Should have considered lower resolutions.

Comment: Hey Phil, can you provide a table with the data of the table? Or maybe is it ok to assume the data of the table is the one that returns your current query? Besides, what DBMS are you using SQL Server/MySQL?

Comment: Thanks Mosty, the DBMS is SQL Server 2008 sorry i should have mentioned that in my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the data you actually have in your table. I just have the data your query returns. You didn't answer to my comment asking for a sample of the data of your table and the DBMS you were using.

However, assuming the current data of your table is the one that comes out of your query, the following query will give you the "Desired Result" you've specified:

```
select t1.* from t t1
left join t t2
on t1.productid = t2.productid and t1.details > t2.details
where t2.details is null
```

In table words, the query turns this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| PRODUCTID | PACKAGEID | DETAILS |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       500 |       0 |
|         1 |       501 |      20 |
|         1 |       502 |      30 |
|         2 |       501 |       0 |
|         3 |       500 |      15 |
|         3 |       504 |      40 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Into this:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| PRODUCTID | PACKAGEID | DETAILS |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       500 |       0 |
|         2 |       501 |       0 |
|         3 |       500 |      15 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Let me know if it's clear or not.

Comment: Thanks Mosty that's an interesting way of achieving the MIN() function and it does seem to work, even though it's obviously a lot more longwinded it certainly gives me the lowest of any particular field. I guess there is no solution in SQL Server that is able to return more than 1 value along with a MIN() aggregate, when composite keys need to be returned. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I've used this trick whenever I need a sub query along with the smallest of something. The idea is to combine the value and key together with the value in the most significant bits and take the min of that. Then take it apart in the outer select.

The best way to combine to values depends on what RDBMS you're using. You don't mention which one you're using so I'm just providing pseudo code:

```
select ..., (tmp.c >> 32) price
from
(select productid, min((price << 32) | packageid) c
  from product_package
  where networkid=1
  group by productid) tmp
inner join product_package ppk on ppk.productid=tmp.productid
  and ppk.packageid=(tmp.c & 0xFFFFFFFF)
inner join product p on p.id=ppk.productid
where p.isenabled=1
```

`<< 32` means shift the value 32 bits to the left and `|` is the bitwise "or". So this is assuming packageid is defined as a 32bit integer (or number(4)). The `& 0xFFFFFFFF` is the bitwise "and" and the hex value for 32 bits used to mask and return just packageid.

Depending on your RDBMS you may need to find its specific syntax for these things or if they're aren't supported you can use plain math - `<< 32` is equivalent to multiplying by 4294967296 and `& 0xFFFFFFFF` to dividing by 4294967296. If you're using MSSQL you can use `convert(binary,price)+convert(binary,packageid)` to combine them and `substring(..)` to separate.

Comment: Thanks Gordy that is another interesting answer, and i was trying something similar with casting the price and packageid together for the MIN() but it was just too damn ugly. Your method is more elegant and I hadn't thought of using math in this scenario.

Comment: @PhilRasmussen: I suppose it depends on how you gauge the ugliness of a query? I'd suggest comparing the execution plans of this approach vs. the one in the answer you accepted. If you really want to pretty it up you could write a user defined aggregate for Min that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Easy (read: expensive) way: build two views: One that gets just the minimum `ppk.price` of each `productid WHERE pk.networkid = 1`, and group that by `productid`. Call it `Product_MinPrice_VIEW` or whatever.

Build a second view, `Product_VIEW`, that replaces all that sub-`SELECT INNER JOIN` work you're trying to get away with via an `INNER JOIN` on the results of the `Product_MinPrice_VIEW` you just made.

I swear, wrangling with sub-`SELECTS`, `HAVINGS` and `GROUP-BY`s is tedious and error prone. I can't stand it sometimes. Hopefully, this will get you far enough to develop a solution that can be later optimized and made more correct.

## FINAL ANSWER

[I have an extremely similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381874/using-a-result-set-from-a-sub-select-when-duplicate-rows-are-encountered) with the application I'm working on, and in the mean time (while I hit this site up for a better answer), I just passed the buck, and wrote some application-level code to deal with any duplicates, and let the program's logic find the true minimum when encountered. Not pretty, but then again I don't have all day to try and figure it out!

I'm sorry my answer couldn't help you. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Droogan thanks for the response. Okay the issue isn't the minimum packageid, it's the minimum price that needs to affect the rows. So if a product has multiple packages, then only return the package with the lowest price. But the catch is i need the productid/packageid returned in order for a unique join back onto that table to get further data. I agree that group bys, and sub-selects are painful especially when multiple columns need to be returned up the tree and multiple aggregate functions are involved :S

Comment: Ah, I'll update my answer then, but I can see where your troubles are. My solution involves cutting out the `packageid` entirely, which may ambiguate the data of the true answer. I'll have to study this more.

Comment: Yep that is exactly where we are running into issues Droggans, we can cut out the packageid, and happily get back a productid and the lowest price, but then we lose our ability to link back to that table to access further data. I would bring all data back initially but this isn't possibly with the MIN(price) and GROUP BY, and i've even tried 3 levels of derived queries with no success. I've never really found a good solution to this type of issue either, as I recall bumping heads with a similar problem in the past.

Comment: Okay, next question; what happens when `productid 1`, `packageid 500` has a price of `0.0`, and `productid 1`, `packageid 501` **also** has a price of `0.0`? Do you just, say whatever, and take `packageid 500`?

Comment: If it helps the Product_Package table looks like this: 

PRODUCT_PACKAGE [id,productid,packageid,packageoptionid,price,selcomproductid,listorder]

id - IDENTITY field and primary key (required for CMS)
productid|packageid - uniqueness constraint

Comment: Correct it will just return whatever is highest in the list. We will probably factor in "listorder" as well to first order the subquery and then perform the MIN() but haven't gotten that far yet.

Comment: Oh no! You have a `UNIQUE KEY` pairing `productid` with `packageid` for this result set. Hmmm...you must have both when determining this stuff. Okay, well, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Droogans i'll check out your other post as well since we seem to be having the same issue, and I'm hoping some SQL DBA guru has some slick solution within the SQL to this issue. Joe Celko? haha. I can also get around this at the application level use grouping, but really wanted to find out once and for all if there was a clean SQL based solution that would contain all my grouping within the Stored Proc and present the application with exactly the dataset it needs for output and manipulation. Appreciate your quick responses!